# Multiple facebook apps under one web application

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use the umbraco cms for a few facebook apps. My idea was to have each facebook app in an aspx page in umbraco (these "apps" are very simple, only a few images, maybe a poll in each). But I can have only one facebookSettings in web.config. Is it possible to not set the facebook app in web.config but set the settings in the code behind? Or is there another way to have multiple facebook apps in one web application (umbraco)?

EDIT: I'm using facebooksdk 5.0.2 beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section 4 of [this post](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-C-SDK-v5-Beta-Internals.aspx) on Prabir's blog for details on how to set Facebook settings in code.

Edit: You will also want to be very careful when managing instances of FacebookClient to avoid confusion ie statics etc.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to first create a new class implementing IFacebookApplication.

```
private class RequestScopedFacebookApplication : IFacebookApplication
{
        private IFacebookApplication Current
        {
            get
            {
                var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
                var app = GetSettingsForUrl(url);
                return app;
            }
        }

        public string AppId
        {
            get { return Current.AppId; }
        }
        /* ....... */
}
```

Then in the Application_Start of global.asax, set your facebook application.

```
public void Application_Start()
{
     FacebookApplication.SetApplication(new RequestScopedFacebookApplication());
}
```

UPDATE: Here is an additional sample implementation: https://gist.github.com/820881

Comment: Can you please explain how I can work with multiple facebook applications in one site? Is it an idea to have multiple IFacebookApplication classes with their own settings and then do FacebookContext.SetApplication whenever necessary?

Comment: try setting the facebook application only in during the application start ie. before your web application is fully loaded.

Comment: put your logic in  "private IFacebookApplication Current {get;}" You can always access the HttpContext.Current.Request from the getter. implement your logic there.

Comment: your GetSettingsForUrl method. Can u explain that briefly?