# C# facebook sdk - Can it handle multiple apps on one website?

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

Your sdk rocks. I have built several apps using the sdk quickly, so thank you for that.

I have searched this topic, but could not find a direct answer.
I will try to explain it as clear as I can.

Like many other developers, I am hosting on our server more than one app.
I have managed to make apps work both from web.config and by passing **IFacebookApplication** to **FacebookContext.SetApplication()**.

As it was mentioned on other posts, setting the configuration programmatically  via FacebookContext.SetApplication() seems to be the only choice for me now.

**The BIG questions:**

1. Is this method setting the
   **IFacebookApplication** for the entire asp.net application? I mean,
   is this change global? Or is it just
   for the current **FacebookClient**?
2. if I have a high user concurrency on
   different fb-apps(on the same
   asp.net application), will calling
   **FacebookContext.SetApplication()** **simultaneously** from each fb-app make errors/collisions?
3. Is it "concurrency safe"?

I will appreciate concrete and direct answers.

Thank you for your great work!

Cheers,
-Itye

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931240/multiple-facebook-apps-under-one-web-application